# Unable to get variable from passing through URL

Tags: javascript, variables, url, onload-event

I have a variable stored `username` and I wish to pass this through a link to the next page. So I have:

```
<a href="register-form.php?username=username">Go!</a>
```

When you land on `register-form.php` there is an `onload` event for the script:

```
<body onload="inputUsername()">

function inputUsername(){
  console.log("I'm running" + username);
  document.getElementById('inputUsername').value = username;
   }
```

However I get an `undefined variable` error for `username`.

**It seems to me that the URL is not passing the variable correctly. Should I be seeing my *actual* variable in the address line? Should I be seeing *username=myusernameisthis* ?**

**In essence, all I'm after is passing the variable `username` from page 1 to page 2. That's all.**

Comment: you should have some code like `var username = <?php echo $_GET[username]; ?>` lets see that

Comment: Do you have the html and/or php code that goes with this?  Just because you have a url parameter doesn't make the page is aware of it.  From javascript, you would have to parse the url to acquire it.

Comment: @Justin or use a server side language like asp or PHP.

Comment: @justin the page register-form.php exists, you can see it [here](http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-registerv3/register-form.php) - the page loads OK it just doesn't understand `username`

Comment: @Francesca Are you trying to submit the page to the server with that data or is it supposed to automatically fill out the username on the form?

Comment: If register-form.php is using a POST method the url variable you describe wont work as it is a GET method. you will have to create a POST request with your username inside and passe it to register-form.php

Comment: @justin - you are correct it is supposed to autofill the username field. It works great when I did it in AJAX but I have decided to make all the pages separate, I just need to work out a way to pass the variable from one page to the next so it can excute that script.

Comment: @Sebastien I'm not sure entirely what you mean. At present, I just want to populate the username input with text, no submission yet (that comes later).

Comment: Essentially I just need the variable `username` to be usable on this page

Comment: @andrew but I would rather use Javascript?

Comment: @Francesca you need to submit (or send a request GET/POST) to passe thing from page to page...

Comment: @Francesca to your newest edit, if you use a query string, yes, you will see them in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters passed in a url query string don't get magically loaded into the javascript global scope.

As @Archios says you can parse the query string with javascript with something like:

```
 var username = getUrlVars()["username"];

 function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = {};
 var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) {
     vars[key] = value;
 });
 return vars;
}
```

but personally I prefer:

```
function inputUsername(){
 var username= "<?php echo isset($_GET[username])?$_GET[username]:''; ?>";
 console.log("I'm running" + username);
 document.getElementById('inputUsername').value = username;
}
```

what would be even easier, is if you changed:

```
 <input id="inputUsername" type="text" name="username">
```

to

```
 <input id="inputUsername" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_GET[username]">
```

and remove the onload event.

the href on the previous page should look something like:

```
 <a href="register-form.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>">Go!</a>
```

assuming `$username` holds the current username

where your script says

```
 username = wordOne + wordTwo + wordThree;
```

add the line

```
 $('.userNameButton a').attr('href','register-form.php?username='+username);
```

Comment: For the second section of code/your preferred method. Where does this go? Inside what function?

Comment: @Francesca I edited the answer to make it more clear

Comment: I added it to the page but I get an error, you can see it here on page load http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-registerv3/register-form.php?username=username

Comment: Seems to me that it doesn't like the line where you call in the PHP along with var = username.

Comment: I missed off  `"` at the start and `";` at the end, sorry about that, I edited above

Comment: OK added! Errors now gone, but it doesn't populate the username with the word that was assigned to it, it literally populates with the string "username". Oops, I still don't think the URL is passing the variable correctly from one page to the next. Have a go yourself with the console open as I have added plenty of code for feedback: http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-registerv3/register-username-builder.php

Comment: Will have a go at your removal of `onload` event, but I expect the same result. It is outputting `username` not e.g `francesca` or `andrew`

Comment: @Francesca actually it works perfectly http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-registerv3/register-form.php?username=andrew you're passing the string `username` in from the previous page by the looks

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to. That is what I am asking for help on. If you re-read the OP you will see me say " the URL is not passing the variable correctly. Should I be seeing my actual variable in the address line? Should I be seeing username=myusernameisthis ?"

Comment: This doesn't work, returns a blank entry for the username. I assume it is because `username` is a JS variable not a PHP variable. See: http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-registerv3/register-username-builder.php

Comment: BTW if you open console on that page, and drag username across to build your username, hit red save buttons, you will see in the console that eventually `username = SparklyPinkFrog` or whatever you have chosen. That is the value of the variable, and it is that that I was asking for advice on as I cannot get it to pass through the URL.

Comment: got there in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

I think You are trying to get query string variable to javascript not to php. Try something like:

[Get query string parameter to js](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an undefined variable error because you have not set the js variable 'username' anywhere.  Setting this in the URL is NOT the same as defining a variable.

If you are setting the URL correctly you shouls see something like 'register-form.php?username=Francesca'

You can do this with a mix of PHP and javascript.

In your register-form.php:

register-form.php:

```
if(isset($_GET["username"])) {
  $username = $_GET["username"];
} else {
  $username = "not set";
}
```

in your js (this is better than calling `<body onload="inputUsername()">`):

```
window.onload=function(){
  var username = <?php echo $username ?>
  console.log("I'm running" + username);
  document.getElementById('inputUsername').value = username;
};
```

Better yet would be to not use js at all and do this all in PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["username"])) {
  $username = $_GET["username"];
} else {
  $username = "not set";
}
?>

<input name="username" id="username" type="text" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
```

Comment: just be careful that `$username` may be undefined, which would result in `var username =` which would produce an error.

Comment: Hi, the username variable has been set already. It is set before the URL and already has a value stored against it.

Comment: @Francesca the username variable has ***not*** been set, not as far as javascript is concerned. the query string can be read easily by php or it can be ***parsed*** in javascript

Comment: I thought this was the setting of the variable? `username = wordOne + wordTwo + wordThree;` - the variable also outputs in the console correctly where I have `console.log("Username = " + username);` - am I incorrect here? If the variable holds a value then it's not set?

Comment: If I use your PHP only version, how is this run when the page loads? What triggers the running of this code?

Comment: Just gave the PHP approach, it populates the textbox with literally "username" - not the variable I previously has assigned on the page before.

Comment: Your URL should look like `register-form.php?username=Francesca` NOT `register-form.php?username=username`.  Is this the case?

Comment: Nope Tims, username is `register-form.php?username=username` - this is what I wrote in the OP, asking if this was correct as I do not see the username in the URL string.

Comment: Then your URL is not correct.  You will need to adjust your first page so that you are creating a link like `<a href="register-form.php?username=Francesca">Go!</a>`  Better yet would be to do this with a POST.  I'll edit my answer to show this.

Comment: @Tims this is what my question was asking. I want to take the value of my username and pass it through the URL. If you re-read the OP you will see me asking how to do this. I don't want to set the URL as username=Francesca as then it won't be a variable.

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding how URL querystrings work.  A querystring holds a field/value pair. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go.  I commented the code so it makes more sense hopefully.  Basically, we get the url from the address bar and parse out the pieces one by one to get what we want.

```
window.ParseQueryString = function () {
    //Get the current location in the address bar
    var url = window.location.href,
        parameterSet = [],
        //Get everything to the right of the '?'
        parameterString = url.split('?')[1];

    //Do we have anything to work with?
    if (parameterString) {
        //Lets get all individual parameter in the parameter string
        var parameterParts = parameterString.split('&');

        for (var i = 0, e; e = parameterParts[i++];) {
            //Get the parameter key and the value
            var parameter = e.split('=');

            //Push it into the array
            parameterSet.push({
                'key': parameter[0],
                'value': parameter[1]
            });
        }
    }

    //Give me my prettyfied query string array plz!
    return parameterSet;
}

console.log(ParseQueryString());
```

Using this code with a window location of http://www.home.com?s=search&f=images will yield:

`[{ key: 's', value: 'search'}, {key: 'f', value: 'images'}]`

With this, in your `onload` callback, you can call the `ParseQueryString` and look through it to find the `username` value and populate it to textbox.

---

### Edit

---

I am added a function that instead of returning an array of key/value pairs, it will return an object with the query string keys as the fields on the object.

```
window.ParseQueryString = function () {
    //Get the current location in the address bar
    var url = window.location.href,
        parameterSet = {},
        //Get everything to the right of the '?'
        parameterString = url.split('?')[1];

    //Do we have anything to work with?
    if (parameterString) {
        //Lets get all individual parameter in the parameter string
        var parameterParts = parameterString.split('&');

        for (var i = 0, e; e = parameterParts[i++];) {
            //Get the parameter key and the value
            var parameter = e.split('=');

            //Add a new field to the object
            parameterSet[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
        }
    }

    //Give me my prettyfied query string array plz!
    return parameterSet;
}
```

Here is a [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/kwFp3/) demonstrating your specific use case.  **Please note that the fiddler is appending a query string to the url as fiddler wouldn't allow it otherwise.  This occurs on line 3**

Comment: @Francesca It should go outside it since this code is getting added to the global scope.  Then in your `OnLoad` event, you would do `var queryString = ParseQueryString();`.  This will return the array with the parts of the query string you can loop through.

Comment: @Francesca Perhaps the fiddler will help in understanding the code.